# Function from $\mathbb{R}^9$ to $\mathbb{R}^6$ with zero set the orthogonal $3\times 3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I am trying to construct a $C^\infty$ function from $\mathbb{R}^9$ to  $\mathbb{R}^6$ with zero set the orthogonal $3\times 3$ matrices.

I am thinking about mapping $M$ to $MM^T-I$, but am not sure how to make the image in $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Any hints?

Comment: I think your idea is correct.  These are symmetric matrices, so they are in a six-dimensional space.  Just ignore numbers below the diagonal because they are the same as the numbers above the diagonal.